# How to blur for background of grid on uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

```
grid background="white"
```

Now, I want to blur it that such as blur on ios.

Comment: You can use opacity to 0.65 - 0.75 to make it blur

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ae270170-5b2a-4412-8603-86e7f0530877/windows-store-app-how-to-apply-blur-to-controls?forum=winappswithcsharp) may help you.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Blur](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/blur) by [UWPCommunityToolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:Blur x:Name="BlurBehavior" Value="25" Duration="0" 
                              Delay="0" AutomaticallyStart="True"/>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Your Content -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If you want to increase or decrease the amount of blur then change the value in behaviours.

If you want any code sample, check out this GitHub project.
[UWP Hamburger Menu with Frosted glass effect and Swipe to Open/Close](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/UWPHamburgerMenu).

Answer (score 5):

Opacity is not a blur effect.
To make a pure blur effect, you will can use the RendertargetBitmap or Win2D.

I prefere to use Win2D because the gaussian blur effect is explicit and can be more precisely configured :

```cs
using (var stream = await Content.RenderToRandomAccessStream())
{
    var device = new CanvasDevice();
    var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, stream);

    var renderer = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, 
                                          bitmap.SizeInPixels.Width, 
                                          bitmap.SizeInPixels.Height, bitmap.Dpi);

    using (var ds = renderer.CreateDrawingSession())
    {
        var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
        blur.BlurAmount = 5.0f;
        blur.Source = bitmap;
        ds.DrawImage(blur);
    }

    stream.Seek(0);
    await renderer.SaveAsync(stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(stream);
    paneBackground.ImageSource = image;
}
```

If you want to read more about it, [here is the MSDN page](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_GaussianBlurEffect.htm).

Comment: Content.RenderToRandomAccessStream() don't have on uwp

Answer (score 4):

You can apply a blur using the Composition APIs with the Windows 10 Anniversary update. However, if you're trying to blur things that are behind the window or app, that won't be possible. On the other hand, if you have something like a picture behind your grid and want the picture be blurred then this will work.

I wrote an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441888/3618768).