# UWP Windows Composition Blur not actually blurring an image

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, composition

I'm working on a UWP application that utilizes Windows Composition API.

There is an image control, named `splitViewSideBarBlur`. The source of this image is set to bitmap of another XAML element, using the following extension method:

```
public static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> RenderToRandomAccessStream(this UIElement element)
{
    if (element == null) throw new NullReferenceException();

    var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rtb.RenderAsync(element);

    var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
    var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
        (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
        (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
        displayInformation.RawDpiX,
        displayInformation.RawDpiY,
        pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    stream.Seek(0);

   return stream;
}
```

I use this extension function to get the image of specific XAML element and save it into a `BitmapImage` variable named `splitViewBlurImage`. This bitmap image is set as the background of a `SplitView` element. Next I apply GaussianBlur and try to set the new blurred image back to the SplitView. However, the new image refuses to be blurred. The following is the code for that:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = await element.RenderToRandomAccessStream())
{
    image.SetSource(stream);
}

ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = splitViewBlurImage;
ib.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
splitViewSideBarBlur.Source = splitViewBlurImage;
splitViewSideBarBlur.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

var graphicsEffect = new BlendEffect
{
    Background = new ColorSourceEffect()
    {
        Name = "Tint",
        Color = Color.FromArgb(95, 255, 255, 255)
    },
    Foreground = new GaussianBlurEffect()
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("Backdrop"),
        BlurAmount = (float)20,
        BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
    }
};

var blurEffectFactory = _compositor.CreateEffectFactory(graphicsEffect,
            new[] { "Blur.BlurAmount", "Tint.Color" });
_brush = blurEffectFactory.CreateBrush();
var destinationBrush = _compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();
_brush.SetSourceParameter("Backdrop", destinationBrush);

var blurSprite = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
blurSprite.Size = new Vector2((float)splitViewSideBarBlur.ActualWidth, (float)splitViewSideBarBlur.ActualHeight);
blurSprite.Brush = _brush;

this.splitViewSideBarBlur.Source = null;
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this.splitViewSideBarBlur, blurSprite);
```

What am I doing wrong here? The background image comes up fine and it has a black-ish tint, but the image is not blurred at all.

Comment: Did you use Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0?

Comment: Hey @DemCodeLines, what version of Windows 10 are you attempting to run this on? There was a known problem with blur on earlier Insider builds but it should be resolved now. Check out [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/wiki/Last-Known-Good) to know what the last known "good" configuration is.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I had to remove all this code and use Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0 as the new Composition APIs are not available in Build 10586 (current general release), so that would mean that only Insiders would be able to run my app.

Comment: @robmikh Hi, I eventually went to the WindowsUIDevLabs GitHub page and used the custom backdrop control that's demonstrated there. Worked perfectly, until I realized that it would only work on Anniversary Update builds, which only Insiders have at the moment. So I've switched to Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0 for now, but look forward to changing back to Composition when the update comes out to everyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP App realtime blur background using DX Compositor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276856/uwp-app-realtime-blur-background-using-dx-compositor)