# How I can make transparent blurred border?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

How I can put the border blurred and transparent in the UWP project like you can see in the picture?

[image: LIKE IN iOS]

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: this looks like iOS and not Widows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This sample](http://metulev.com/render-xaml-to-image-and-more/) should help you.

Key thing is to render UI under panel to image and then blur it.

**Render UI Element to image:**

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(); 
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement); 
image.Source = rtb;
```

**Make image Blured using [UWP Community toolkit:](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/)**

```
await image.Blur(duration: 10, delay: 0, value: 10).StartAsync();
```

Or, yes, like @MZetko answered [use new Anniversary SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441888/1558147)

Answer (score 1):

To make a `Border` background transparent, you can just set its background to a transparent or semitransparent color:

```
<Border Background="#ABFFFFFF" />
```

The hexadecimal value of the color consists of four two-character values - Alpha, Red, Green and Blue. the Alpha part determines the transparency. When set to `00` the color is fully transparent, when set to `FF` it is opaque.

If you actually want to achieve a blur effect like that on the picture, you will need to target the Windows 10 Anniversary Update SDK and use the new Composition API. This is very well [described in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276856/uwp-app-realtime-blur-background-using-dx-compositor).