# How do you blur an image in Windows 10 XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I've looked all around this site and have yet to find a way to blur an image in XAML. I've tried some functions in C#, but they haven't worked. I'd like to achieve the blurred background image, like in the Audiocloud app (https://store-images.s-microsoft.com/image/apps.28769.9007199266467874.da79334d-0f1c-4851-8e0b-7ee566918b20.0658cd96-487e-4e1f-a330-10fb030aaa22?w=443&h=788&q=60). How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP App realtime blur background using DX Compositor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276856/uwp-app-realtime-blur-background-using-dx-compositor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

1. Add Microsofts `Win2D.uwp` NuGet package to your project. (Right click your project in Solution Explorer > "Manage NuGet packages...")
2. Have this example XAML UI:

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Image x:Name="myBackground" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
       <Image x:Name="myImage" Width="360" Height="300" Source="Assets/test.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageOpened="myImage_ImageOpened"/>
   </Grid>
   ```
3. Create an Extension Method for `UIElement` in a static class:

   ```
   static class Extension
   {
       public static async Task<IRandomAccessStream>
           RenderToRandomAccessStream(this UIElement element)
       {
           RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
           await rtb.RenderAsync(element);

           var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
           var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
           var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

           var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
           var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
           encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                                (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
                                (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
                                displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                                displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                                pixels);

           await encoder.FlushAsync();
           stream.Seek(0);

           return stream;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use it. For example in your `public sealed partial class MainPage : Page`:

   ```
   private async void BlurThisUI(UIElement sourceElement, Image outputImage)
   {
       using (var stream = await sourceElement.RenderToRandomAccessStream())
       {
           var device = new CanvasDevice();
           var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, stream);

           var renderer = new CanvasRenderTarget(device,
                                                 bitmap.SizeInPixels.Width,
                                                 bitmap.SizeInPixels.Height,
                                                 bitmap.Dpi);

           using (var ds = renderer.CreateDrawingSession())
           {
               var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
               blur.BlurAmount = 5.0f;
               blur.Source = bitmap;
               ds.DrawImage(blur);
           }

           stream.Seek(0);
           await renderer.SaveAsync(stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);

           BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
           image.SetSource(stream);
           outputImage.Source = image;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Call it. In this example when the image was opened (see the XAML above: `ImageOpened="myImage_ImageOpened"`):

   ```
   private void myImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       this.BlurThisUI(myImage, myBackground);
   }
   ```
6. Credits goes to Nikola Metulev by [this tutorial](http://metulev.com/render-xaml-to-image-and-more/)

#### Note

As you can see, you can not just use this to blur images but also any `UIElement` (for example a grid with all its containing UI elements like buttons, checkboxes etc.)

#### all the usings

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas;
using Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects;
```

Comment: Awesome..Thanks !

Comment: Having a lot of trouble with this in Win 10 UWP. If I set "myImage"'s source in the code (because I've loaded from a file I've chosen rather than setting the source in XAML) the ImageOpened event isn't getting raised (nor Loaded or others I've tried), even if I set the underlying BitmapImage to await the SetSourceAsync.

Comment: Also RenderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync().ToArray() is unavailable for me. Instead I had to do: var buffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
                DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                byte[] pixels = new byte[buffer.Length]; reader.ReadBytes(pixels);