# (UWP) The new AcrylicBrush class isn't working for me

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

So I'm trying to use the new features that are available in the latest Windows SDK that Microsoft has provided, and no luck. I get the error:

"Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush' is not registered."

I'm running Windows 10 Creators Update and using Visual Studio Pro 2017. And as I stated, I have the latest preview SDK installed. Now the features are supposed to work on Creators Update. Some of Microsoft's own apps are even making use of the new Brush features.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AcrylicBrush is not available in the Creators Update (Build 15063). It is available in starting in Insider Preview 10.0.16190.

See the "Windows 10 Requirements" block at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush

Apps can achieve similar effects in the Creators Update through the [Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor)'s CreateHostBackBrush.

There is sample code targeting Creators Update at https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2015063/TransparentWindow

Also see [How to use Acrylic Accent in Windows 10 Creators Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699256/how-to-use-acrylic-accent-in-windows-10-creators-update)

Comment: Oh, so the Paint 3D app in Creators Update doesn't use the new effect features shown at build? The titlebar of Paint 3D has a noisy texture effect that was shown at build, which I'm trying to implement. Or maybe there is another way? O_o

Comment: I don't believe so, but I don't have a CU system handy. Build was mostly looking at new features for the Fall Creators Update and beyond. Paint 3D with Acrylic is available in current post-CU Insider Previews. Acrylic, etc. are built on the low level Composition API which was available in the CU, so you can get similar effects: you just need to assemble them yourself rather than having prebuilt brushes.

Comment: The blur effect is available since the Anniversary Update. The Acrylic APIs are just a new way to use it. Here is how you can implement blur: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276856/uwp-app-realtime-blur-background-using-dx-compositor/36441888 If you want the window to be transparent, this is possible in the current Creators Update.