# c# uwp blur part of the screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, blur, windows-community-toolkit

I am using UWP Community Toolkit to create blur as following:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridContent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:Blur x:Name="BlurBehavior"
                Value="0"
                Duration="0"
                Delay="0"
                AutomaticallyStart="True"/>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

And this works just fine for the whole grid.

But, my problem is now that there is a listview in this grid, and I want to make custom header in that listview that will be semi transparent, and I want just content under that header to be blurred. So the content under that header will be dynamically changed.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP App realtime blur background using DX Compositor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276856/uwp-app-realtime-blur-background-using-dx-compositor)

Comment: (OR there's the new acrylic system they're working on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/style/acrylic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `Header` of the `ListView` is scrollable along with the content. A more elegant solution would be to extract the header template to be **outside** of the `ScrollViewer` and blur it. Note you will need to give the content a padding to give space to the header initially, and the *top* padding value should be equal to the height of the header.

You can do everything within a style -

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewHeaderHeight">200</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="ListViewContentMargin" Top="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderHeight}"></Thickness>

    <Style x:Key="BlurredHeaderListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="{StaticResource ListViewContentMargin}" FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}" FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderPresenter" Background="Transparent" Height="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderHeight}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <behaviors:Blur x:Name="BlurBehavior" Value="12" />
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you just apply the style to any `ListView` you want -

```
<ListView Style="{StaticResource BlurredHeaderListViewStyle}">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <sampleapp:CustomHeader />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

---

### Result

[image]

Comment: Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]

Comment: Do you know what did I done wrong? I included     xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations.Behaviors"

Comment: Make sure you have [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `Blur` in a separate `grid` inside your content `grid`

Here is a code sample

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <ListView>
        ....
    </ListView>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:Blur Value="25" Duration="0" Delay="0" AutomaticallyStart="True"/>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <!-- If you want color shade -->
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

For more info refer [UWP Hamburger Menu with Frosted glass effect](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/UWPHamburgerMenu)

Comment: This will only blur the content of the container, not what's behind it.

Comment: No. Try it first. I have used this method to create Frosted glass effect in HamburgerMenu. Here is a code sample [UWPHamburgerMenu](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/UWPHamburgerMenu)

Comment: How to make this header to be fixed, it is moving now?

Comment: @user3239349 If you want fixed header then there is no point of using `ListView.Header`. Just put the header content above the ListView.

Comment: @user3239349 What happened?

Comment: How to make panel that will make evertything behind it to be blurred? (content behind it is listview that is scrollable)

Comment: This works great. I have test it, it really blur just the content behind it, make frost glass look with this. Thanks alot. :)

Comment: @Jessica That's what he wants